# How can we find an exhaustive list (or graph) of all logos which are effectively recognized using Google Vision logo detection feature?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

With my work team we are wondering which logos are referenced in the list (or graph) used by the Google Vision API.
Apparently, there are a lot of very famous logos which are not recognized at all in pictures.

For instance, on the following picture, only 5 results are returned by the Google Vision API (and "Google" logo does not belong to those results). Obviously, the max result parameter is already set to 40.

[Famous logo to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss24Q.png)

But, here, the question is not really why the LOGO_DETECTION feature does not work well but more : "How can we have the garantee that the logo exists in the Google Vision's database (or graph) and that it could be recognized by the API at more than 0%?"

On the other hand, the logo detection feature is not free so, how can we paid without the garantee that the logo we are interested in belongs to the Google logos list (or graph)? Is there a way to check if the logo can be recognized or if there is any location where we can see all the logos referenced?

Answer (score 1):

On a similar question in a mailing list Google has specified they do not give out a full list of possible matches for various reasons.

The only way you could have a guarantee is to have at least one positive detection for that logo. So kind of bruteforcing it seems like the only way unfortunately.